# how to stop hibernate from recreating tables?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Every time I run my application, all my data will be erased, how to stop it in application.properties? 
I know it's a dumb question

Comment: What database are you using? I had once the same problem with H2 database behaving exactly like this.

Comment: @ViktorChvátal I'm using mysql, how did you fix it?

Comment: have you set property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto?

Comment: If you have the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in you config set to value `create`, change it to `update`

Comment: @ViktorChvátal I fixed it thanks mate, I found spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create and changed it to update